# Slim framework project error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, pdo, slim

I've created a new project:

[image: 1]

Project tree you can see at the right of the screen and database at the left.

My home.php file:

```
<?php

$app->get('/',function() use($app) {

    $posts = $app->db->query("
        SELECT
        posts.*
        FROM posts
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON posts.pAuthor = users.id;
    ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    var_dump($posts);
    die();

})->name('home');
```

My index.html file:

```
<?php

    require '../app/start.php';
```

My routes.php file:

```
<?php

    require 'routes/home.php';
```

My start.php(main app file):

```
<?php

require '../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
//    DATABASE
$app->container->singleton('db',function(){
    return new PDO('mysql:127.0.0.1;dbname=blog','root','');
});

require 'routes.php';

$app->run();
```

And after trying to open my project I had an error occured:

[image: 3]

Is there something wrong? 
I'm following this lesson: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRfYgco3xo4(not PR).

Comment: Did the answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something wrong?

Yes. If you copy-paste something, then do it right.. You forgot `host` while initialize `PDO`.

```php
$app->container->singleton('db',function(){
    return new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=blog','root','');
});
```

Comment: Please provide a short explanation instead of code-only answers. And if I see correctly, that's exactly the same code as used in the original question, isn't it?